# Retrieving data from interface returning enums

Tags: java, enums

I have received a project to solve that uses Enums and I am a bit stuck. It's a tic tac toe game that has enums that store the locations of cells in a 3x3 grid table, and enums that store the state of the cells (empty, X, or O). Plus I have an interface for the `GameBoard` that returns `CellState`: `getCellState (CellLocation cellLocation);`

My task is to write the `Consultant` interface only and I cannot change anything in the code that was provided to me.
I am struggling to check the status of the `Board` before each step.

My idea was that X starts the game, I use a `for` loop for steps and at each step, I check `if nrOfSteps%2==0`. If **yes**, I set the `cellState` to player O. Check if we are at winning position, if we have won or if there's a draw. If not, I will suggest a move.
E.g.

```
if (nrOfSteps%2!=0){
    cState =CellState.OCCUPIED_BY_X;
      if (isWon(cState, board)){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Player X won!");
      } else if (draw(board, locations)){
        throw new IllegalStateException("No more empty fields!");
      } else
        for (int remainingCells = 0; remainingCells <9; remainingCells++) {
            if (board.equals(locations[remainingCells]) && 
            cState==CellState.EMPTY){
            availableCells[index] = locations[remainingCells];
            index++;
        }
        CellLocation cellToTake = availableCells[(int)(Math.random()*
        (availableCells.length-1))];
        return cellToTake;
}
```

Now, my problem is that I have tried the following for the `isWon` method (partial code validating only the first row for now):

```
private boolean isWon(CellState player, GameBoard board){
if (board.equals(CellLocation.TOP_LEFT) && cState==player &&
    board.equals(CellLocation.TOP_CENTRE) && cState==player && 
    board.equals(CellLocation.TOP_RIGHT) && cState==player){
  return true;
}

return false;
}
```

But I have realized that the current Status of the board could not be equal to only one cell as I am checking in the above code. And it obviously cannot be equal to 3 different "only one cell"-s. And I am not even sure if I could be checking if the board had only one cell occupied by player X by this:

```
board.equals (CellLocation.TOP_LEFT) && cState==player
```

Could someone please give a tip on how I can incorporate both the `CellState` and `CellLocation` into one query? Should I use arrays? e.g. `CellState[][]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the sums of the cells in the matrix(for each column, row and diagonal). Like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class CrossAndZeros {
    private static CellState winner;
    private static Enum[][] field = new Enum[3][3];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < field[i].length; j++) {
                field[i][j] = CellState.values()[new Random().nextInt(3)];
            }
        }

        for (Enum[] enums : field) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(enums));
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Winner is found: " + isWinnerFound());

        System.out.println(winner == null ? "No winner, GAME OVER" : winner);
    }

    private static boolean isWinnerFound() {
        int[] result = calculate();
        int count = 0;

        for (int win : result) {
            if (win == 3) {
                winner = CellState.OCCUPIED_BY_X;
                return true;
            } else if (win == -12) {
                winner = CellState.OCCUPIED_BY_O;
                return true;
            } else if (win == -9 || win == -2 || win == -3) { // This means that the line is spoilt
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count == 8; // If all the lines are spoilt, the game is over
    }

    private static int[] calculate() {
        int[] result = new int[8];

        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < field[i].length; j++) {
            result[i] += getCellOwner(field[j][i]); // a column
            result[i + 3] += getCellOwner(field[i][j]); // a row
        }
        result[field.length * 2] += getCellOwner(field[i][i]); // diagonal
        result[field.length * 2 + 1] += getCellOwner(field[i][field.length - i - 1]); // diagonal

        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

        return result;
    }

    private static int getCellOwner(Enum cell) {
        switch ((CellState) cell) {
            case OCCUPIED_BY_O:
                return -4;
            case OCCUPIED_BY_X:
                return 1;
            case EMPTY:
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public enum CellState {
        /**
         * this cell is occupied by player X
         */
        OCCUPIED_BY_X,

        /**
         * this cell is occupied by player O
         */
        OCCUPIED_BY_O,

        /**
         * this cell is Empty
         */
        EMPTY
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I have tried your code and altered it a bit because the interface I have to write will have a "public CellLocation suggest (GameBoard gameBoard)" method that returns null.
So it doesn't have a main method and the JUnit test that was pre-written for me looks at this suggest method. I will have to delegate the tasks from here. 
But this way I cannot convert enums in the for loop to cellLocation to return only one location.
And it is showing an error for the getCellOwner method saying that it cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Can you show your CellState and CellLocation classes?

Comment: I posted it as an aswer because it didn't let me post it into a comment. Thanks.

Comment: I've changed my answer

Comment: @Vero Was my answer helpful? Can you choose it as the right answer? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, sorry, your answer was helpful, but I didn't have the means to finish the assignment or reply here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

the CellLocation enum:

```
public enum CellLocation {
    /** The Cell in the top row and leftmost column */
    TOP_LEFT,

    /** The Cell in the top row and centre column */
    TOP_CENTRE,

    /** The Cell in the top row and rightmost column */
    TOP_RIGHT,

    /** The Cell in the centre row and leftmost column */
    CENTRE_LEFT,

    /** The Cell in the centre row and centre column */
    CENTRE_CENTRE,

    /** The Cell in the centre row and rightmost column */
    CENTRE_RIGHT,

    /** The Cell in the bottom row and leftmost column */
    BOTTOM_LEFT,

    /** The Cell in the bottom row and centre column */
    BOTTOM_CENTRE,

    /** The Cell in the bottom row and rightmost column */
    BOTTOM_RIGHT;
}
```

the CellState enum:

```
public enum CellState {
/** this cell is occupied by player X */
OCCUPIED_BY_X,

/** this cell is occupied by player O */
OCCUPIED_BY_O,

/** this cell is Empty */
EMPTY;
```

}